# Is this exponential growth?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, combinatorics

If I have 4 cells where each cell can contain 1 or 2 . Therefore 4^2 is the number of combinations of values in all 4 cells. If each cell can contain 1 or 2 or 3 then the number of combinations of values in all 4 cells is 4^3. Is this exponential growth ? How can be represented in terms of big o notation ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer, so this question can be ticked off.  By all means find a duplicate and hammer this ...

Does the sequence `4^2, 4^3, 4^4, 4^5, ...` (or `16, 64, 256, 1024, ...`) grow exponentially ?

Yes.

And you might write it `O(c^n)`.